# Music decreases fps in android 5.0 lolllipop version(nexus tab10) cocos2dx

Tags: android, animation, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, android-5.0-lollipop

I am creating a game using cocos2d-x version 2.2.x, most of the part of this game has been completed and it is working well on all android devices except Nexus 10. The game was working well on nexus 10 before but now i have updated my nexus tab to android 5.0 (lollipop) . Now I have started encountering some issue related to audio.
The problem is that whenever my game plays any music file the frame from drops down 60 to 1, because of that all my animations stop. I am using ".mp3" format for all the sound files.

Comment: Test if this is related with your problem https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/9088/files

Comment: this does not work for me, this link is related to play background music,my game fps decreases in when i play effect

Comment: Can you try using .ogg files instead? I'm using XLD (http://tmkk.undo.jp/xld/index_e.html) to convert.

Comment: I tried .ogg format, but it also does not work

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with android 5.0 and the `simpleAudioEngine`

Google have altered the mediaplayer, which the simpleAudioEngine is using, some game ca not run at all on Android 5.0

luckily,  there is a much improved audio engine in v3.3, you can try to copy that audio engine into your v2.2.x

Comment: Thanx for reply, I tried to copy v3.3 audio engine into v2.2, but i failed, if you have any idea or solution please tell me

Answer (score 0):

New AudioEngine in `cocos2dx3.3` is work fine in `Android 5.0.`

A little differ between `cocos2dx2.2` and `cocos2dx3.3`.
https://github.com/chenzepei/Cocos2dx2.2-AudioEngine